# my IP address is different to remote address at EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have been trying to restrict access to a port on an EC2 box to a single remote computer (my desktop).

The various "what is my IP" services around on the Internet all consistently report an IP address IP1.

However, when I look in the access logs on the EC2 box, I see my address is actually recorded as IP2.

Not surprisingly, restricting access only works properly (via EC2's security group rules, or iptables) when I use this IP2 address.

Now my question:  is it Amazon EC2 which is translating my address as some point, or are all the "what is my IP" services (consistently) wrong?  Either way, what is different about EC2?

Comment: Needs more detail. What country are you in? Are you proxied by your ISP or government? Did you try an IP address web site that shows your proxy server information? How are you connecting to the server?

Comment: Australia; Telstra mobile broadband; http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test says my request doesn't appear to have come from a proxy (although there probably is, but still why would the box at EC2 see things differently?). Connection to the server is via plain old GET requests in a web browser (Chrome or whatever).  Host is in EC2 eu-west.

Comment: Are you connecting to the instance through an Elastic Load Balancer?

Comment: No, just straight in.  I should say that reverse IP lookup services say that the IP address IP2 belongs to Telstra (my local ISP), so this isn't an IP address EC2 is allocating.  The question is how/why is EC2 seeing a different address to other sites?  I guess it is possible that Telstra has some logic which handles connections to EC2 differently to connections to other sites...

Answer (score 1):

usually most illogical issues have the most trivial explanation...
Try checking your source IP against EC with something that is not proxy-prone/easy-to-manipulate.
e.g.
on EC2: #tcpdump -n -i any icmp
on your PC: ping  
of course you have to open ICMP from any at AWS firewall for this ...

Comment: That reveals the same source IP as I see in my access logs - different from the various "what is my IP" services.

Comment: great, now you can conclude:  
- EC has nothing to do with it (no mangling or whaever)  
- Someone is messing with your browsing of the Internet, as all the
what-is-my-ip services give you IP belonging to your ISP, most probably your ISP have some sort of transparent proxy where only web traffic is being routed via different IP.  
The best way to know - ask your ISP. Also you may try https://www.whatismyip.com/ and see if it gives you a different IP (https/SSL is much harder to tamper with than plain http)

Comment: I agree with your conclusion that EC2 has nothing to do with it (except insofar as it sees things a little differently).  Surprisingly, what is my IP gives the same result for both http and https/SSL - different to what EC2 sees.  I'll post a question on whirlpool to see what people know about what Telstra is doing, and report back...\